# Wordpress Front Product Edit link change to wp-admin edit product (edit button coming from wc-vendor plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using wc-vendor pro plugin which maks a simple dashboard for vendors to handle products - products can be added, edited and removed from there.
But the requirement is: on click edit it should go in wp-admin product post and edit same product.

I have this filter to change the URL but I don't know how to get same product ID?
  Any help?

```
add_filter( 'wcv_product_edit_link', 'link_actions_edit', 10, 3);
function link_actions_edit($template_url, $product_id) {
  $template_url  = '/wp-admin/post.php?php='. $product_id.'&action=edit';  
  return $template_url;
}
```

And here is the plugin code.

```
/**
     * Get the product edit link depending on several different variables
     *
     * @since  1.4.0
     * @access public
     * @return array $product_edit_link
    */
    public static function get_product_edit_link( $product_id = null, $default = false ){

        $default_template   = get_option( 'wcvendors_product_form_template' );
        $default_template   = 'edit' === $default_template ? 'standard' : $default_template;
        $default_link       = ( 'standard' === $default_template ) ? 'product/edit/' : 'product/' . $default_template . '/edit/';

        // Only load a custom template if the product has one
        if ( $product_id ){
            $template   = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wcv_product_form_template', true );
            $template   = $template === 'edit' || $template === 'standard' ? '' : $template;
            if ( !empty( $template ) ) $template = $template . '/';
        }

        if ( $default )  $template  = $default_link;

        $template_url = ( empty( $template ) ) ? $default_link : 'product/' . $template . 'edit/';

        return apply_filters( 'wcv_product_edit_link', WCVendors_Pro_Dashboard::get_dashboard_page_url( $template_url . $product_id ) );

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the **wrong parameters** in the filter function.

*Follow this to change your code:*

```
function link_actions_edit($param) {
  $home_url       = get_home_url(); 
  $remove_http    = str_replace('http://', '', $param);
  $split_url      = explode('/', $remove_http);
  $get_product_id =  $split_url[4];

  $product_edit_url  = $home_url . '/wp-admin/post.php?post='. $get_product_id.'&action=edit'; 
  return $product_edit_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$split_del_prd_imgs = (explode(',', $delelte_product_images));

```
                     foreach($split_del_prd_imgs as $img_name) {
                        
                        ("products_img/" . $_GET["prd_id"] . "/" . $img_name);
```